# How do I sort a VARCHAR column in SQL server that contains numbers?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a `VARCHAR` column in a `SQL Server 2000` database that can contain either letters or numbers. It depends on how the application is configured on the front-end for the customer.

When it does contain numbers, I want it to be sorted numerically, e.g. as "1", "2", "10" instead of "1", "10", "2". Fields containing just letters, or letters and numbers (such as 'A1') can be sorted alphabetically as normal. For example, this would be an acceptable sort order.

```
1
2
10
A
B
B1
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: also note that IsNumeric returns 1 for values 24e4 and 12d34

Comment: Faced this problem, came here. Saw your question, noticed a wrong assumption. You said "Fields containing just letters, or letters and numbers (such as 'A1') can be sorted alphabetically as normal." Try ordering A1, A2 and A10. You will get A1, A10, A2. Now that I finished with the question part, I will be looking for an answer below. Hopefully I find one :)

Comment: @anarkhalilov did you?

Comment: @ahsteele, to be honest, it is quite challenging for me to recall after three and a half years.

Comment: @anarkhalilov I assumed you wouldn't but figured it was worth the ask. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

One possible solution is to pad the numeric values with a character in front so that all are of the same string length.

Here is an example using that approach:

```sql
select MyColumn
from MyTable
order by 
    case IsNumeric(MyColumn) 
        when 1 then Replicate('0', 100 - Len(MyColumn)) + MyColumn
        else MyColumn
    end
```

The `100` should be replaced with the actual length of that column.

Comment: I have found that one of the fields in our test database contains 12345678901234567890 which causes problems with the other solutions. Admittedly this is unlikely to happen on a live customer database, but if it did, this solution would be able to handle it successfully.

Comment: Had to change char(0) to '0' to make it to work... otherwise this is solid. The other solutions given here did not work well for descending sort if there are null on the table

Comment: char(0) is null which causes the result to be null, so one should use instead '0'

Comment: thank you so much as long you replace char(0) with 0 in the above this works great!

Comment: Works great! And you can add "desc" after the end to sort in other direction. In which case the strings will show first.  I like how this solution doesnt actually pad the numbers in the result output.

Answer (score 15):

There are a few possible ways to do this.

One would be

```
SELECT
 ...
ORDER BY
  CASE 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(value) = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT, value) 
    ELSE 9999999 -- or something huge
  END,
  value
```

the first part of the ORDER BY converts everything to an int (with a huge value for non-numerics, to sort last) then the last part takes care of alphabetics.

Note that the performance of this query is probably at least moderately ghastly on large amounts of data.

Comment: The tables tend to be simple 'reference' tables, and don't have a huge number of rows (A few hundred at most, so performance wouldn't be a major issue).

Comment: Going by the experts exchange article I link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119730/how-do-i-sort-a-varchar-column-in-sql-server-that-contains-numbers#119796 I think you have to cast to MONEY then INT to avoid '$' being read as numeric

Answer (score 5):

```
select
  Field1, Field2...
from
  Table1
order by
  isnumeric(Field1) desc,
  case when isnumeric(Field1) = 1 then cast(Field1 as int) else null end,
  Field1
```

This will return values in the order you gave in your question.

Performance won't be too great with all that casting going on, so another approach is to add another column to the table in which you store an integer copy of the data and then sort by that first and then the column in question. This will obviously require some changes to the logic that inserts or updates data in the table, to populate both columns. Either that, or put a trigger on the table to populate the second column whenever data is inserted or updated.

Comment: *slaps head* So it does! Well, did... have patched it now. Did my classic mistake of fiddling with a working solution after testing! Well spotted, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(int, your_column) AS your_column_int
FROM your_table
ORDER BY your_column_int
```

*OR*

```
SELECT *, CAST(your_column AS int) AS your_column_int
FROM your_table
ORDER BY your_column_int
```

Both are fairly portable I think.

Comment: +1 for simplicity and succinctness.  Unlike the others, this is super easy to glance at and understand.  My only question is would it still sort if there were cases where the data wasn't numerical?

Comment: As OP stated, `your_column` includes letters too. Your proposed solution will not work for values including letters.

Answer (score 5):

you can always convert your varchar-column to bigint as integer might be too short...

```
select cast([yourvarchar] as BIGINT)
```

but you should always care for alpha characters

```
where ISNUMERIC([yourvarchar] +'e0') = 1
```

the +'e0' comes from http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/isnumeric-isint-isnumber

this would lead to your statement

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table
ORDER BY
   ISNUMERIC([yourvarchar] +'e0') DESC
 , LEN([yourvarchar]) ASC
```

the first sorting column will put numeric on top. 
the second sorts by length, so 10 will preceed 0001 (which is stupid?!)

this leads to the second version:

```
SELECT
      *
    FROM
      Table
    ORDER BY
       ISNUMERIC([yourvarchar] +'e0') DESC
     , RIGHT('00000000000000000000'+[yourvarchar], 20) ASC
```

the second column now gets right padded with '0', so natural sorting puts integers with leading zeros (0,01,10,0100...) in correct order (correct!) - but all alphas would be enhanced with '0'-chars (performance)

so third version:

```
 SELECT
          *
        FROM
          Table
        ORDER BY
           ISNUMERIC([yourvarchar] +'e0') DESC
         , CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([yourvarchar] +'e0') = 1
                THEN RIGHT('00000000000000000000' + [yourvarchar], 20) ASC
                ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM([yourvarchar]))
           END ASC
```

now numbers first get padded with '0'-chars (of course, the length 20 could be enhanced) - which sorts numbers right - and alphas only get trimmed

Answer (score 4):

I solved it in a very simple way writing this in the "order" part

```
ORDER BY (
sr.codice +0
)
ASC
```

This seems to work very well, in fact I had the following sorting:

```
16079   Customer X 
016082  Customer Y
16413   Customer Z
```

So the `0` in front of `16082` is considered correctly.

Comment: I had only numeric values in a varchar field that needed to be sorted. This worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
select your_column  
from your_table  
order by   
case when isnumeric(your_column) = 1 then your_column else 999999999 end,  
your_column
```

Answer (score 0):

This query is helpful for you. In this query, a column has data type varchar is arranged by good order.For example- In this column data are:- G1,G34,G10,G3. So, after running this query, you see the results: - G1,G10,G3,G34.

```
SELECT *,
       (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(column_name) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) IsNum
FROM table_name 
ORDER BY IsNum, LEN(column_name), column_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, I have tried this when i got the same issue.

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
ORDER BY IIF(TRY_CAST(val AS INT) IS NULL, 1, 0),
         TRY_CAST(val AS INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and efficient way to get the job done is using TRY_CAST

```
SELECT my_column 
FROM my_table
WHERE <condition>
ORDER BY TRY_CAST(my_column AS NUMERIC) DESC
```

This will sort all numbers in descending order and push down all non numeric values

Answer (score 0):

I combined some answers from here to this:

```
SELECT MyStringColumn,
       (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(MyStringColumn) = 1 THEN Cast(MyStringColumn as int) ELSE 999999999 END) MyNumericColumn 
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY MyNumericColumn, MyStringColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many of the answers provided above, none seem to work for me until i adjust the query this way - everything seems to be fine:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY CAST(myVacharColumn AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

Comment: That is because the question is asking for a solution in SQL Server. Though, the question was tagged with SQL so any answers for other RDBMSes are good too. Just to say: your answer will not work in T-SQL / SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT FIELD FROM TABLE
ORDER BY 
  isnumeric(FIELD) desc, 
  CASE ISNUMERIC(test) 
    WHEN 1 THEN CAST(CAST(test AS MONEY) AS INT)
    ELSE NULL 
  END,
  FIELD
```

As per [this link](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/Q_23258510.html) you need to cast to MONEY then INT to avoid ordering '$' as a number.

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC (ID)=1 THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(20,2),SUBSTRING(Id, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Id), LEN(Id)))END DESC)Rn ---- numerical
        FROM
            (

        SELECT '1'Id UNION ALL
        SELECT '25.20' Id UNION ALL

    SELECT 'A115' Id UNION ALL
    SELECT '2541' Id UNION ALL
    SELECT '571.50' Id UNION ALL
    SELECT '67' Id UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B48' Id UNION ALL
    SELECT '500' Id UNION ALL
    SELECT '147.54' Id UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A-100' Id
    )A

    ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC (ID)=0                                /* alphabetical sort */ 
         THEN CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Id)=0
                   THEN LEFT(Id,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Id))
                   ELSE LEFT(Id,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Id)-1)
              END
    END DESC
```