# Order By Clause for NVARCHAR column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-order-by, nvarchar

I need to make the order by for the `nvarchar` column. The issue is this that the column doesn't have the same pattern of entry, example of some rows of the column are

```
12    
9     
TEF      
78F    
T2R
```

How to sort this column by order By clause? The only relief I have is that this column contains only numeric and alpha numeric characters.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Is `order by <nvarcharColumn>` not working?

Comment: @Sachin No it is not working correctly. By doing that it feels like that it is not at all sorting the records

Comment: So how does it sort your example column?

Comment: What is the desired output then for this input? And why?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite - Can you show some sample results you are getting and the result which you are expecting? That would help.

Comment: I was adviced by my client to sort it. He is expecting output like first numeric value than alphanumeric. In this case. 9 , 12,78F, T2R, TEF

Comment: There are many different possible output orders that *might* be desired, other than the string sorting (what you'd get by just saying `order by column`). For instance, you might want all purely numeric values to sort first, and sorted numerically (so 2 comes between 1 and 10), or more complex rules (e.g. all values *starting* numerically sorted by numeric rules, then by string rules for the remained). You need to tell us what rules you think "make sense" in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ORDER BY
   RIGHT(REPLICATE(N' ', 500) + MyValue, 500)
```

So

```
9
12
78F
T2R
TEF
```

becomes

```
            9
           12
          78F
          T2R
          TEF
```

Which will sort correctly

You can't rely on ISNUMERIC

Comment: Can you please explain the logic you used in this statement. I am new in sql server

Comment: Simply, it add leading spaces which are included in the sort

Comment: And yet 'A' would sort between '9' and '12' here... Still, if the OP's client is happy, great.

Comment: @Andriy M: This solution kind of assumes there is some length element too to the sort too: so 9<A<12

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    *
from
    table
order by
    CASE
       WHEN not column like '%[^0-9]%' THEN CONVERT(int,column)
       WHEN column like '[0-9]%' THEN CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(column,1,PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',column)-1))
    END,
    CASE
       WHEN not column like '%[^0-9]%' THEN NULL
       WHEN column like '[0-9]%' THEN SUBSTRING(column,PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',column),9000)
       ELSE column
    END
```

Comment: +1 for most sensible answer but even then, what do you do with decimals, scientific notation etc? The client would do well to define the desired behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you issue is that its not sorting the numbers and text correctly.

This article explains one approach:

[How do I sort a VARCHAR column in SQL server that contains numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119730)

From the article:

```
select MyColumn
from MyTable
order by 
    case IsNumeric(MyColumn) 
        when 1 then Replicate(Char(0), 100 - Len(MyColumn)) + MyColumn
        else MyColumn
    end
```

Comment: IsNumeric is pure evil, unless you happen to like that `'1d2'` is numeric, but `'1g2'` isn't.

Comment: ugh! Mental note to self. +1 to your question for pointing that out

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: This is very interesting - do you know of anywhere this behaviour is explained or at least documented?