# How to Show data from a column separated by Character values first and then numeric values in sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server-2012

Suppose i have a table

```
id  Values
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   7
5   J
6   K
7   L
```

Now i want an output like

```
id  Values
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   J
5   K
6   L
7   7
```

How this can be achieved ?

Comment: You can have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119730/how-do-i-sort-a-varchar-column-in-sql-server-that-contains-numbers

Answer (score 0):

Generate `ROW_NUMBER()` with independent sorting on each column using subquery/CTE and join using generated rn:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0f99e/7/0)**

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT
   [id],
   rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id)
  FROM tab
)  
,cte2 AS
(
  SELECT
   [values],
   rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN  LEFT([values],1) LIKE '%[A-Z]%'
           THEN 1 
           ELSE 2
         END, [values])
  FROM tab
)  

SELECT c1.id, c2.[values]
FROM cte c1
JOIN cte2 c2
  ON c1.rn = c2.rn;
```