# Sort numbers then strings C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I want to this list

```
A
B
C
111
11
123
1
42
5
```

To be sorted

```
1
5
11
42
111
123
A
B
C
```

By default, it sorts numbers like strings (So, it goes 1,11,111,123,42,5),
But I want to sort numbers like numbers, and than strings that are not numbers.

Is there clean solution to sort it like above?

It is a list of objects, and object has several properties, one of which is a this string.

Comment: What type is your list to start with? What have you tried already?

Comment: Are your numbers represented as strings, or are they integers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119730/how-do-i-sort-a-varchar-column-in-sql-server-that-contains-numbers

Comment: `list.GroupBy(s => int.TryParse(s, out var ignore)).OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).SelectMany(g => g.Key ? g.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s)) : g.OrderBy(s => s));`

Comment: that might technically work, but I feel sorry for the next programmer after you who has to figure out what that line of code is doing, lol

Comment: @JoeIrby That's what comments are for ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for most use cases, but may have odd results if the string starts with control characters, string like "\tabc" will come before the integers:

```
list.OrderBy(x=>int.TryParse(x, out var dummy) ? dummy.ToString("D10") : x);
```

or for versions of C# prior to 7:

```
list.OrderBy(x=> { int dummy; return int.TryParse(x, out dummy) ? dummy.ToString("D10") : x;} );
```

Comment: You know you could do `dummy.ToString("D10")` instead of another parse.

Comment: @juharr Updated answer that doesn't require two parses, and added a pre C# 7.0 version.

Comment: Why use `D10`? I don't understand

Comment: @RoadRunner I just picked 10 as the numbers he gave used less than 10 digits.  `.ToString("D10")` makes a string 10 digits long, left padded with 0's, so `1.ToString("D10")` creates a string "0000000001" which then will be sortable.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this `IComparer` implementation a few months back to handle something like this.  I think it will do what you want by default, though it is built to handle more complex cases where number/letter groups are separated by delimiters that also need to be sorted atomically.  You should be able to adjust it to your needs.

```
public class SemanticComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private static Regex _splitter = new Regex("\\W+");

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        string[] partsX = _splitter.Split(x);
        string[] partsY = _splitter.Split(y);

        int shortest = Math.Min(partsX.Length, partsY.Length);

        for (int index = 0; index < shortest; index++)
        {
            int intX, intY;
            int result;

            if (int.TryParse(partsX[index], out intX) && int.TryParse(partsY[index], out intY))
            {
                result = intX.CompareTo(intY);
            }
            else
            {
                result = string.Compare(partsX[index], partsY[index], StringComparison.Ordinal);
            }

            if (result != 0)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

You can sort your list with it like this:

```
MyList.Sort(new SemanticComparer());
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called [Natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order).

I once wrote some code for that:

```
public static class NaturalCompare
{
    public static int Compare(string first, string second, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.Ordinal)
    {
        if (string.Compare(first, second, comparison) == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (first == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (second == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        DateTime d1, d2;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(first, out d1) && DateTime.TryParse(second, out d2))
        {
            return d1.CompareTo(d2);
        }

        var pos1 = 0;
        var pos2 = 0;

        int result;
        do
        {
            bool isNum1, isNum2;

            var part1 = GetNext(first, ref pos1, out isNum1);
            var part2 = GetNext(second, ref pos2, out isNum2);

            if (isNum1 && isNum2)
            {
                result = long.Parse(part1).CompareTo(long.Parse(part2));
            }
            else
            {
                result = String.Compare(part1, part2, comparison);
            }
        } while (result == 0 && pos1 < first.Length && pos2 < second.Length);

        return result;
    }

    public static int CompareToNatural(this string first, string second, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.Ordinal)
    {
        return Compare(first, second, comparison);
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByNatural<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, string> keySelector)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(keySelector, new NatComparer());
    }

    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByNaturalDescending<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, string> keySelector)
    {
        return source.OrderByDescending(keySelector, new NatComparer());
    }

    private sealed class NatComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            return NaturalCompare.Compare(x, y);
        }
    }

    private static string GetNext(string s, ref int index, out bool isNumber)
    {
        if (index >= s.Length)
        {
            isNumber = false;
            return "";
        }

        isNumber = char.IsDigit(s[index]);

        var start = index;
        while (index < s.Length && char.IsDigit(s[index]) == isNumber)
        {
            index++;
        }
        return s.Substring(start, index - start);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all the values once, and use int.TryParse to separate them into two separate lists: one for the values where int.TryParse returned true (aka the numbers), and another list for the ones where it returned false (the non-numbers).  Then you could sort these two lists separately, and concatenate their sorted results together at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code for performance, but you can solve this with a Comparer

```
public class ArrayItemComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        int xInt = 0, yInt = 0;

        bool parseX = int.TryParse(x, out xInt);
        bool parseY = int.TryParse(y, out yInt);

        if (parseX && parseY)
        {
            return xInt.CompareTo(yInt);
        }
        else if (parseX)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (parseY)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return x.CompareTo(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a solution for this. I've divided the `list` into two part then sort and concat. Please check below:

```
public List<ListItem> getSortedList()
{
    int dummy = 0;

    List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>();
    list.Add(new ListItem() { Item = "A" });
    list.Add(new ListItem() { Item = "B" });
    list.Add(new ListItem() { Item = "C" });
    list.Add(new ListItem() { Item = "111" });
    list.Add(new ListItem() { Item = "11" });
    list.Add(new ListItem() { Item = "123" });
    list.Add(new ListItem() { Item = "1" });
    list.Add(new ListItem() { Item = "42" });
    list.Add(new ListItem() { Item = "5" });

    var listNumber = list.Where(m => int.TryParse(m.Item, out dummy)).ToList().OrderBy(m => Convert.ToInt16(m.Item)).ToList();
    var listString = list.Where(m => !int.TryParse(m.Item, out dummy)).ToList().OrderBy(m => m.Item).ToList();

    var sortedList = listNumber.Concat(listString).ToList();

    return sortedList;
}
```

You can run this in [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rfs3du).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you start with a collection of strings, a simple comparer should do the job:

```
public class Comparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string a, string b) 
    {
        int ia = 0;
        int ib = 0;
        var aIsInt = int.TryParse(a,out ia);
        var bIsInt = int.TryParse(b,out ib);
        if (aIsInt == bIsInt)
        {
            if (aIsInt)
            {
                return ia.CompareTo(ib);
            }
            else
            {
                return a.CompareTo(b);
            }
        }
        return aIsInt ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rxFjJu)

Answer (score 0):

With Regex.Replace in the "OrderBy" it's one (fairly) simple line of code.  And note that the number "3" just has to be a number equal-to or larger than your longest string, so for anyone else increase as needed.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string[] yourStrings = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "111", "11", "123", "1", "42", "5" };

foreach (var item in yourStrings.OrderBy(x => Regex.Replace(x, @"\d+", i => 
i.Value.PadLeft(3, '0'))))
{
    Response.Write(item + "\n");
}
```