# Order mixed string/number column with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-order-by

In my database, I have a column which can contain either only numbers, or text (which can also contain numbers). For `char` columns, SQL server sorts value by character code (1, 12, 14, 2, 20, 200, 3, 30, ...).

How would I have to write my `.OrderBy` statement to sort them like numerics, when they are numeric?

Comment: Use the correct design where you stored numbers in a numeric datatype and strings in a string datatype?

Comment: Are you trying to sort in EF or SQL?

Comment: @DaleBurrell That doesn't work in my case. My table contains names of storage locations, and they can be alphanumeric. But I want to treat the number part as a number. So if the code would be AB-234-Z, that should come after AB-30-Z, not before.

Comment: @DaleBurrell With the EF6 `.OrderBy` method. But I could also build a database view in SQL, if that would simplify the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort on DB ( *not on application* ), then

use `patindex()` and `substring()` functions to extract the integer part of your column( *considering null cases as zero* ), and then cast as integer :

```
Order By cast( coalesce(
                substring(yourCol, patindex('%[0-9]%', yourCol), 
                   patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', yourCol + 't') 
                   - patindex('%[0-9]%', yourCol) + 1)

               ,0)  as int )
```

within your select statement.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=74120007cd8584e6da20acca6c0533ff)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much! Is that code efficient, though? It looks rather complicated.

Comment: I see another problem with an SQL based solution: Views can not contain a sort statement. Do I need to write a table function for that, or is there an easier solution?

Comment: @AndréReichelt you're welcome. Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions, while some other DBMS do, so the way is complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I still have the problem, though, that I cannot simply translate that into an Entity Framework Linq.

Answer (score 0):

How about this SQL:

```
SELECT MyStringField,
       (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(MyStringField) = 1 THEN Cast(MyStringColumn as int) ELSE 999999999 END) MyNumericField
FROM MyEntity
ORDER BY MyNumericField, MyStringField
```

See also:
[How do I sort a VARCHAR column in SQL server that contains numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119730/how-do-i-sort-a-varchar-column-in-sql-server-that-contains-numbers/)

I used the following C# snippets in order to get this behavior:

DataContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(s => s.MyNumericField).HasComputedColumnSql("CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([MyStringField]) = 1 THEN Cast([MyStringField] as int) ELSE 9999999999999 END");
```

MyEntity:

```
public class MyEntity
{
  //...
    [Required]
    public string MyStringField
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public decimal MyNumericField
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
  //...
}
```

Linq query:

```
var result = await query.OrderBy(x => x.MyNumericField).ThenBy(x => x.MyStringField).ToListAsync();
```