# How could I go about sorting dates I have saved as nvarchar in SQL

Tags: sql

Say I am trying to sort through and I want to see the dates 10/22/2020, 10/23/2020, 10/24/2020, and/or 5/5/2020. How could I do this? When I run with the following code it will not work.

```
AND appointmentsTable.scheduledDate = @startDate 
AND appointmentsTable.scheduledDate = @date2
AND appointmentsTable.scheduledDate = @date3
AND appointmentsTable.scheduledDate = @endDate
```

[Screenshot of query I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAkTt.png)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119730/how-do-i-sort-a-varchar-column-in-sql-server-that-contains-numbers

Answer (score 2):

You would convert to a date:

```
order by convert(date, appointmentdate, 101)
```

But you should fix your data model so dates are stored as `date`s.

Comment: Sorry, where would I insert this line?
The problem is that when I attempted to bulk load the CSV file, the dates only loaded if they were of type string. How could I do this?

Comment: @YeslynCasasola . . . `order by` goes at the end of a `select` query.